# IBM DB2 // Create Alias in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I using the latest edition of IBM´s DB2 Express-C. In one of my stored procedures I am trying to add a CREATE ALIAS - Statement for an existing table.

"Unexpected token" is the error message after executing the create statement for the stored procedure.

So my question:
I read the documentation for [CREATE ALIAS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createalias.dita). There is no limitation to a special context. Does anybody implment the CREATE ALIAS in a stored procedure successfuly?

This is a snipped from my DBProc:

```
   DECLARE SQL          varchar(450);

   SET T1 = 'M2F.m2f_k' || i_TableNr;
   SET T2 = 'M2F.m2f_k' || i_TableNr || '_zuodoc z' ;

   -- CREATE ALIAS M2F.Kxx FOR T1;
   CREATE ALIAS M2F.Kxx FOR M2F.m2f_k11;

   for_loop: 
   FOR rs AS c1 CURSOR FOR
```

Thank you!
Oliver

Comment: This little testing Stored Procedure is not working as well:
create procedure M2F.test() 
language sql
BEGIN ATOMIC
   CREATE OR REPLACE ALIAS M2F.Kxx FOR TABLE M2F.m2f_k11;
END

Comment: Why are you referencing documentation for DB2 for z/OS, if you are working with DB2 for LUW?

Comment: I am sorry. This ist the correct link: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DDL statements, including `CREATE ALIAS`, must be executed dynamically in stored procedures:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE ALIAS M2F.Kxx FOR ' || T1;
```

Here's a [link to the manuals](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-56&lang=en) *for the latest version* of DB2 for LUW.

Comment: Hey mustaccio, this is working. I am already using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in other Stored Procedures, but in this case never thought of it :-(